# Picture height and width before uploading

Tags: javascript, image, validation, upload, dimensions

I am trying to validate the image uploaded by the user. So, after the user adds its image, before uploading it on the server, I tried validating the image dimensions with the javascript code below but it won't work.

```
function check_image_dimensions(){
var t=document.getElementById("main_file_1");
e=t.clientWidth;

n="";
o="We could not upload your image because \n \n";
if (e<300) {
(n+="The height of the image must be greater than 300px \n";
}
if(i<300){
n+="The height of the image must be greater than 300px \n";
}
```

I also tried:

```
e=t.width;
i=t.height;
```

But it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What is main_file_1, an img tag, or the file input tag?

Comment: It's the id I gave to the image. I have: <input type="file" id="main_file_1" name="main_file_1">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like:

1) Put the image in a hidden `<img/>` element

See this example: [MDN - Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images)

2) Check the size (bounding box) of the `<img/>` element

```
if(img.getBoundingClientRect().width<300) ...
```

3) Alert the user (or not)

**Here is a working version: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/nry4h/).**

Browser Compatability: 
Firefox 3.6+,
Chrome 7+,
IE 10+,
Opera 12+

Comment: Slick.  'Probably worth referencing the supported browser list - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Thanks! I am still looking into the hidden img but I will look into implementing your answer more.

Comment: Do you have another question?  What is your question on the hidden img?

Comment: Hello, sorry to answer so late. Yes, I couldn't figure out how to add the hidden img around it. Should I do it via Javascript or on html? Sorry, I am new with all of this and I am still finding my way. Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to help you more in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40764/image-upload-check-size).  I want to understand your question.

Comment: Not a very clean way, but it's really simple. I'd rather go with this. It would work in any browser.